# Bash - how to replace a single line starting with a pattern with multiple lines defined in a variable?

Tags: bash, replace, sed, grep, heredoc

I have a file that at some point contains a line like the following:

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="/afs/sern.ch/user/l/lronhubbard/virtual_environment"
```

It is the sole line in the file that begins with `VIRTUAL_ENV`. Using a script, I want to replace this line with the following lines:

```
directory_bin="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"
directory_env="$(dirname "${directory_bin}")"
VIRTUAL_ENV="${directory_env}"
```

How could this be done?

To start with, I've got the replacement lines stored in a here document in the script:

```
IFS= read -d '' text << "EOF"
directory_bin="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"
directory_env="$(dirname "${directory_bin}")"
VIRTUAL_ENV="${directory_env}"
EOF
```

Next, I can replace the line in the file with something else (here, `xxx`) using `sed`:

```
sed -i "s/^VIRTUAL_ENV.*/xxx/g" test.txt
```

Now, how can I use the defined here document variable `${text}`, with all of its newlines and whatnot, instead of `xxx` in the `sed` command?

---

EDIT: Following the suggestion by rslemos, I have implemented the following using a temporary file instead of a here document:

```
#!/bin/bash

temporary_filename="$(tempfile)"

cat > "${temporary_filename}" << "EOF"
directory_bin="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"
directory_env="$(dirname "${directory_bin}")"
VIRTUAL_ENV="${directory_env}"
EOF

sed -i "/^VIRTUAL_ENV.*/ {
   r ${temporary_filename}
   d
}" test.txt

rm "${temporary_filename}"
```

I'd still like to know how to use a here document directly so that I'm not unnecessarily using the hard drive.

Comment: Please don't post an answer as part of the question.  If you want to add an answer of your own, post it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with `sed` alone:

```
/^VIRTUAL_ENV/{
r source.txt
d
}
```

Where source.txt is the file where lie the new lines to replace a line starting with "VIRTUAL_ENV".

If you really need the new lines (source.txt) to be a here document, the `/dev/fd/0` trick will work (in Linux at least). But you could also combine `mktemp` and `mkfifo`.

**EDIT**

To address the "*I'd still like to know how to use a here document directly*":

```
!/bin/bash

sed -e '/^VIRTUAL_ENV/{' -e 'r /dev/fd/0' -ed -e'}' test.txt << "EOF"
directory_bin="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"
directory_env="$(dirname "${directory_bin}")"
VIRTUAL_ENV="${directory_env}"
EOF
```

Not very portable, because of the `/dev/fd/0` part (works in Linux, though).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):

```
cat <<\! | sed $'/PATTERN/{r /dev/stdin\n;d}' file
HERE DOCUMENT
STUFF
HERE
!
```

Use `cat` to pipe the `stdin` into the sed command and read it as a file using `r` command.

N.B. `\!` quotes all text in the here document use `!` to interpolate variables. `$'...'` allows commands needing a newline (i.e. sed commands such as `r`,`a`,`i`,`c`,`R`,`w`,`W`) to be written as one line.

Answer (score 0):

Many dialects of `sed` allow you to escape newlines in the substitution:

```
sed -i 's/^VIRTUAL_ENV.*/directory_bin="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"\
directory_env="$(dirname "${directory_bin}")"\
VIRTUAL_ENV="${directory_env}"/' test.txt
```

That's a single-quoted string spanning three lines, with a backslash added for continuation at each internal line boundary.

This is not portable to every `sed` variant out there, but works fine on *BSD (including OSX) and Linux at least.

Incidentally, you could also simply put all of these commands on a single line, with semicolons between them.

Comment: The `/g` flag was clearly useless here, so I took it out.